# How to fix a live search using jQuery in my table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have been trying to understand how to be able to make a live search in my table.
Right now I'm able to search item when im press my "Search-button". Is there any solution to this in .Net core?

This is my controller right now

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        var foundItems = SearchItem(search);
        return View(foundItems);
    }

    return View(await _context.Storage.ToListAsync());
}

public List<Storage> SearchItem(string search)
{
    var result = _context.Storage.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

And this is my View

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="POST">
<div class="row input-group" id="searchbar">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Search storage" autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="Sök" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="backtoviewbtn" value="Back" class="btn 
    btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>

 <table class="table" id="listTable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Storages
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="tdclick" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Stocks", new { 
             id=item.StorageId })'">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();

$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

        $row = $(this);

        var id = $.map($row.find('td'), function(element) {
        return $(element).text()
        }).join(' ');


        if (id.indexOf(value) <0) {
            $row.hide();
        }
        else {
            $row.show();
        }
    }
});
});
```